# How do I reduce WeChat storage size on Android?

Tags: storage

Wechat takes up a huge amount of storage space on my phone (Moto G5 plus). Almost all of it is due to the Wechat cache (which has ballooned to 11gb) but neither the app nor my phone settings allow me to clear the Wechat cache. When I use File Manager to open the Tencent-Micromsg-xlog folders, I see that a lot of space is taken up by files like MM_20190420.xlog or MM_20190430.xlog. What are these? Can I delete them to free up space? Otherwise, how do I clear my wechat cache? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Select "Me" on bottom panel. Then Settings > General > Manage Storage. For the cache, I have a "Clear" button on the this screen and was able to clear the cache by pressing it.

On this screen, can also press "Manage" which brings up another screen where you can select conversations from which to remove all pics, videos, and attached files. Text msgs are kept. Don't know about audio msgs. After pressing orange "Delete" button *on my version* a warning window popped up telling you what's about to deleted and asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleted the xlog folders, nothing happen, looked safe, but over time it will built up again, so I keep deleting them from time to time.